# python convert a string to a logic gate function

Tags: python

I have a python string like: `"(a and b and c) or (d and e)"`, where a, b, c, d and e are conditions of some kind. As you can probably see, this is actually a logical expression.

I'd like to somehow convert it into a logic-gate-like function, say, *f*. So I would pass a number of true conditions to *f*, and get the logical results. Examples:

- If I pass it `(d and e)` (i.e., d and c are true), *f* returns **True**.
- If I pass it `(a and b and c)`, *f* returns **True**.
- If I pass it just `a`, *f* returns **False**.
- If I pass it just `b and c`, *f* returns **False**.

I have no idea how to tackle such a question. `strtobool` doesn't quite handle my requirements, and I'm not sure how to even convert the given string into a function. As for passing it true conditions as input, I'm thinking of passing it a list of `True` booleans, i.e. all conditions are `False` by default. e.g. from the first example above:

```
d = True; e = True
f([d, e])
> True

d = True; e = False
f([d])
> False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Essentially, you can do-

```py
eval('d and e', {'d': True, 'e': False})
```

Which passes the `d and e` string to evaluate, and also passes in some globals, to set the value of those variables.

It's often better to use the third argument, locals, instead of globals however.

```py
eval('d and e', {}, {'d': True, 'e': False})
```

This will achieve the same thing, except `d` and `e` are set in local scope, the second argument is just empty.